# Proving a characterization of the Dense Linear Subspaces on a Normed Space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $(E, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ a normed space over a field $\Bbb{K}$ and $M$ a linear subspace of $E$ . Then, $$\overline{M}=E \iff \forall f \in E' : f(M) = \{0\} \rightarrow f(E) = \{0\}$$

($E'$ is the set of linear functionals from $E$ to $\Bbb{K}$)
I am proving this result that appears as an excercise in a book I found on the library.

For the left-to-right implication, take $f \in E'$ such that $f(M) = \{0\}$ . Given $y \in f(E)$ it exists $x \in E : f(x)=y$ . Since $\overline{M}=E$, it exists $\{x_n \}_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \subset M : \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x$

Since $f$ is a functional, is bounded and then continuous. This with $f(M) = \{0\}$ and $\{x_n \}_{n \in \Bbb{N}} \subset M$ implies that $y = f(x) = f(\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} 0 = 0$ .

I am having problems to see the another implication, so any possible help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\forall f \in E' : f(M) = \{0\} \rightarrow f(E) = \{0\}$ but $E \setminus \overline{M} \neq \emptyset$ and take $x \in E \setminus \overline{M}$ . This means that $d(x, M) > 0$ . Let denote $f : span\{x\} + M \rightarrow \Bbb{K}$ the linear operator defined as $f(a x + v) = a \, d(x, M)$ . By its definition, $|f(a x + v)| = |a| d(x, M) \leq |a| \lVert x + \frac{1}{a} v \rVert = \lVert ax + v\rVert$, so $f \in (span\{x\} + M)'$ .

The Hahn-Banach Theorem implies that this functional extends to another with the same norm on $E$, call it $F : E \rightarrow \Bbb{K}$. Now, oberve that $F(M) = f(M) = \{0\} \implies F(E)= \{0\} \implies 0=F(x)=f(x)=d(x,M)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much!